# Import a maven project into netbeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, import

I'm learning how to create some applications in Java, i found a maven project example in a tutorial and went to compile it in netbeans.

I tried to search in the Internet how to **import a maven project into netbeans**, and i can't found a solution.

By the way, in the tutorial i downloaded something like pom.xml, i wonder what is it and how it can be used?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use code markup for things that are not code.

Comment: From memory, you need to start with a Maven project

Comment: [maven in 5 mins](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) + [open existing project](http://wiki.netbeans.org/MavenBestPractices#Open_existing_project)

Comment: i downloaded something like pom.xml, i wonder what is it ? - Briefly speaking pom defines the complete project how it is to be handled by the IDE/compiler and how it is built. Defines all the dependencies, any repositories if you wish to use any specific ones and any plugins which you wish to use. 

and how it can be used - In the very basic of its usage you wont have to edit if manually, the IDE will do that for you, for advance usages yes you might want to understand its structure

Answer (score 22):

You can import Eclipse Maven project in netbean, just follow the steps.

1) In Netbean , File->New Project->Select maven in left Pane -> Select Project with existing POM on right pane and finish.

2) Now you will be asked to open a eclipse project just open it and that's it..

I hope you will solve your problem with this......

Comment: It should be an accepted answer, the current accepted one contains only link.

Answer (score 1):

Although not really a direct solution to your problem, a work around to get you up and running is to create a maven project in Netbeans via the wizard, with the same name as the example project you want to install. Then, create the same package structure in the project as the example, then copy the files into their correct packages. Although you are not importing the project, but it should get you up and running.