# Netbeans to use pom.xml (Maven) instead of build.gradle (Gradle)

Tags: java, maven, gradle, netbeans, pom.xml

Our team has a Netbeans 11.0 project that (at the root level) contains both a **pom.xml** file and a **build.gradle** file. When opening the project within Netbeans it assumes it is a Gradle project and treats it as such. However the default should be to open as a Maven project, allowing the pom.xml to take precedence.

Is there any configuration within Netbeans that will tell it that this is a Maven project (to use the pom.xml file) and treat it as such?

(note, if we close the project, *temporarily* delete the build.gradle file, then re-open in Netbeans, it does open as expected as a Maven project)

Comment: Import project as Maven project in Netbeans. Check this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20846641/import-a-maven-project-into-netbeans

Comment: [1] Do you want the project to be a Maven project or a Gradle project? If the answer is "both" then explain why, because that would be a very unusual requirement. If you are transitioning from Maven to Gradle (or vice versa) then just branch your project. And even if everything seems to work, having a project with both configurations is just asking for trouble. [2] Regardless of that, temporarily deleting the **build.gradle** file seems unnecessarily drastic. Why not just rename it (e.g. **build.gradlex**) so that it will be ignored rather than deleting it?

Comment: Thanks for the responses all! @skomisa [1] anyone opening this in NetBeans should reference it as a Maven project, other developers (in different IDEs) prefer the Gradle build process; it may seem odd, but it allows our engineers to use the tools they are experts in. [2] we've done that currently, but it still means renaming it each time for a Gradle build is annoying :)

Comment: OK, your motivation kind of makes sense, though I have never come across this requirement before. But if your team needs to toggle between using gradle and maven, then renaming **gradle.build** seems as simple as any other approach. Maven developers need do nothing, and gradle developers would rename **build.gradlex**. You obviously have to change _something_ to force NetBeans to choose between maven or gradle, and you shouldn't really mess with configuration data which is for NetBeans internal use only. If you had a magic wand to solve the problem what would your solution be?

Comment: Thanks again for your response. I was hoping that for a NetBeans project you could tell NetBeans the project is either Maven or Gradle, instead of it just inferring one or the other (in this case it seems to pick Gradle which is wrong).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now on newer versions (using 12 here), in Tools/Options/Java/Gradle exists a checkbox "Prefer Maven Projects over Gradle (needs restart)", check that and you have the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Netbeans 11 and newer will consider the project as gradle if both **pom.xml** and **build.gradle** files exist in the project.

I had the same problem and found no option to tell Netbeans that I want to treat my project as being maven and not gradle.

Solution is (as @skomisa commented) to rename **build.gradle** and **settings.gradle** to something else like **build.gradle_disabled**, **settings.gradle_disabled** and then Netbeans will see your project as maven

Answer (score 0):

The only way I managed to convince netbeans 11 to use my pom.xml:
Close the project, close netbeans.
Clean up the cache folder (in Linux: ~/.cache/netbeans/11.0)
Restart netbeans, reopen the project.