# how to use JFxtras with Scenebuilder on Netbeans 8.2?

Tags: java, netbeans, scenebuilder, jfxtras

I m a newbie to scenebuilder and JavaFX , all I know is how to configure scenebuilder on Netbeans to use it hehe XD

I m working on a school project and I liked the very useful controls that JFxtrats offers and I want to use them ( i m planing to use ICalendarAgenda )

but I have no idea how to even import or install or whatever ... to make JFxtras working on my ide ( Netbeans 8.2 )
can you please help me?

will be very appreciated!!

PS: Operating System is Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to learn about Maven; you need a good build tool anyhow if you want to do anything more than some very basic Java.
https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Follow the instructions at OpenJFX to create a Maven based JavaFX project.
https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven

Import that project into Netbeans.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20846641/import-a-maven-project-into-netbeans#:~:text=You%20can%20import%20Eclipse%20Maven,open%20it%20and%20that's%20it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20846641/import-a-maven-project-into-netbeans#:%7E:text=You%20can%20import%20Eclipse%20Maven,open%20it%20and%20that%27s%20it.).

Include a dependency to jfxtras-icalendaragenda in the pom.xml.
https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.jfxtras/jfxtras-icalendaragenda/11-r1/jar

And you should be able to use the component.

But there are a lot of things to know, things you need to learn and understand, before you can really start coding. For example: how do I use the FXML generated by scenebuilder? There is no shortcut.

Comment: i Only need the IclanderAgenda module from JFXtras, i tried to import the jar to my project library folder and to import it to the a FXML file but it didn't work

Comment: Correct, because icalendar-agenda uses agenda, which uses controls, which uses common. You did not do what I described. Again: there are no shortcuts.

Comment: i will try your instructions and return to you as soon as possible but i just want to add that while i was searching about this issue i found some stuff about using jfxtras whitout maven
here is a link please take a look : 
https://www.reddit.com/r/java/comments/2cfzt5/how_to_add_jfxtras_to_current_project_without/

Comment: Sure, if you want to you, can download each and every library separately. We (the Java community) use to do that up until 2004-ish, since then Maven or Gradle takes care of that. I'm not saying my approach is the one with the smallest getting started, but it most definitely worth the effort. But you're welcome to; jfxtras is not too complex in its dependencies.